# Change font family dynamically throughout app

Tags: ios, uikit, swift4, multitargeting

I am working on one multitarget project where it consists of two apps with each having its own branding.

I have distinguished app name, app icon, and branding color of the app but now I need to switch fonts family of the app dynamically after fetching branding details from API.

The problem I am trying to solve is keeping same font sizes but with different font family.

I tried finding a way out to keep the font sizes same with different font family but didn't succeed, Please let me know if you have any suggestions to solve this particular case.

Comment: assuming you are using UIFont(...) to set your information but have you looked into using attributes instead?

Comment: @dniswhite all the fonts are set on the storyboard. Is there any way we can use a different font family for the different target using storyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve this problem through method swizzling. Following are steps to solve this problem:

- Step1: Create an extension of UIFont and the following code to override font name and family runtime.

Code Example:

```
  var appFontName = "ArialMT"
  var appFontBoldName = "Arial-BoldMT"

 extension UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName {
   static let nsctFontUIUsage = UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName(rawValue: "NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute")
 } 

extension UIFont {

@objc class func mySystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: appFontName, size: size)!
}

@objc class func myBoldSystemFont(ofSize size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont(name: appFontBoldName, size: size)!
}

@objc convenience init(myCoder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    guard let fontDescriptor = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "UIFontDescriptor") as? UIFontDescriptor else  {
        self.init(myCoder: aDecoder)
        return
    }
    let face = fontDescriptor.object(forKey: UIFontDescriptor.AttributeName.face) as? String ?? "Regular"
    var fontName = appFontName

    switch face {
    case "Regular":
        fontName = appFontName
    case "Bold":
        fontName = appFontBoldName
    default:
        fontName = appFontName
    }
    self.init(name: fontName, size: fontDescriptor.pointSize)!
}

class func overrideInitialize() {
    if self == UIFont.self {
        let systemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(systemFont(ofSize:)))
        let mySystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(mySystemFont(ofSize:)))
        method_exchangeImplementations(systemFontMethod!, mySystemFontMethod!)

        let boldSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(boldSystemFont(ofSize:)))
        let myBoldSystemFontMethod = class_getClassMethod(self, #selector(myBoldSystemFont(ofSize:)))
        method_exchangeImplementations(boldSystemFontMethod!, myBoldSystemFontMethod!)

        let initCoderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIFontDescriptor.init(coder:)))
        let myInitCoderMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, #selector(UIFont.init(myCoder:)))
        method_exchangeImplementations(initCoderMethod!, myInitCoderMethod!)
    }
  }
}
```

- Step2: (Usage) and call the overrideInitialize method.

  ```
  UIFont.overrideInitialize()
  ```

It preserves Font size by changing font family throughout your app. :)

Answer (score 0):

Update the visual appearance of an entire application in minutes using [NUI](https://github.com/tombenner/nui). You just have to define themes like `Theme1.nss` and `Theme2.nss` in two different files then AppDelegate's  `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method you just tell the NUI framework to load those theme accordingly to targets

> if Target1
>
> ```
> [NUISettings initWithStylesheet:@"Theme1"];
> ```
>
> #elif Target2
>
> ```
> [NUISettings initWithStylesheet:@"Theme2"];
> ```
>
> #endif

Comment: NUI library seems very old and it's written in Objective C

Comment: it didn't worked for you? We still use it in our projects.